# How can I cycle through hex color codes in PHP?

Tags: php, colors

I want an array where each field in the array contains a color code

```
array(0 => '#4CFF00', 1 => '#FFE97F')
```

And I want this to go through the whole spectrum of colors starting from green to black.

green->  blue -> dark blue -> purple -> yellow -> orange -> red -> brown ->black

This order doesn't need to be exactly the same, but I think you get the picture.
Can anybody help with this? Is there a website that has done this before?

Comment: there's an awful lot of colours in the spectrum from from green to black.  Do you want them all or just the ones you've listed?

Comment: You know those color charts where it looks like a rainbow and the colors smoothly transition from one shade to another?  I think that is what he wants, but he wants to generate it in an array.

Comment: from green to black? your `#FFE97F` is white … `#4CFF00` is green though. so what’s up with the black? wrong code example? or wrong understanding on my side?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use a colour model like [Hue-Saturation-Value (HSV)](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html), and cycle the hue from 0 degrees all the way around the spectrum to 360 degrees, at which whatever saturation and value suited you. (If you want to go from green->green, just start at 120 degrees)

Here's an illustration which shows the difference between RGB and HSV based gradients: the top gradient is just going from green to red in an RGB model, but the lower one uses HSV, resulting in a more pleasing effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

00FF00 is Green 000000 is Black. all you have to do it increment one color at a time while decrementing the other colors. Stick it in a loop, where it be php, javascript or whatever and go.

**EDIT:**
Here is a link to code that shows how to [loop](http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/hexcolors_2.htm) through Hex color codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
function dechexpad($i){
$s="";
if($i<16) $s="0";
$s.=dechex($i);
return $s;
}
function hexcolor($r,$g,$b){
return "#".dechexpad($r%255).dechexpad($g%255).dechexpad($b%255);
}

$xx=array();
for($i=0;$i<255;$i++){
$xx[]=hexcolor($i*4,$i*2,$i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function list_colours($start, $end, $steps = 6)
{
    $return = array();

    $start_r = hexdec(substr($start, 1, 2));
    $start_g = hexdec(substr($start, 3, 2));
    $start_b = hexdec(substr($start, 5, 2));

    $end_r = hexdec(substr($end, 1, 2));
    $end_g = hexdec(substr($end, 3, 2));
    $end_b = hexdec(substr($end, 5, 2));

    $shift_r = ($end_r - $start_r) / $steps;
    $shift_g = ($end_g - $start_g) / $steps;
    $shift_b = ($end_b - $start_b) / $steps;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $steps; $i++)
    {
        $color = array();
        $color[] = dechex($start_r + ($i * $shift_r));
        $color[] = dechex($start_g + ($i * $shift_g));
        $color[] = dechex($start_b + ($i * $shift_b));

        // Pad with zeros.
        $color = array_map(function ($item) {
                return str_pad($item, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            },
            $color
        );

        $return[] = '#' . implode($color);
    }

    return $return;
}

// Examples
$spectrum = array();
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#000000", "#FFFFFF"); // grey
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#cc0033", "#FFFFFF"); // R
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#ff6600", "#FFFFFF"); // O
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#fdc710", "#FFFFFF"); // Y
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#cccc00", "#FFFFFF"); // G
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#339933", "#FFFFFF"); // G dark
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#339999", "#FFFFFF"); // B teal
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#14acde", "#FFFFFF"); // B light
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#0066cc", "#FFFFFF"); // B dark
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#663399", "#FFFFFF"); // I dark
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#990066", "#FFFFFF"); // I light
$spectrum[] = list_colours("#cc0066", "#FFFFFF"); // V pink
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some color schemes? I think it depends on the color scheme of the rest of your page. You can google "Color scheme generators" and you can find at least 10. Examples provided by @edg and @santiiiii above.

If you have a photo, there is a tool which can get colors from the photo to fit your site.

```
http://www.atalasoft.com/31apps/ColorSchemeGenerator/
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing a function to do this.  If you need to go between multiple colors, just call it multiple times and concatenate the arrays.

```
Psuedocode: `colorRange(arrayReference, startColor, endColor, numSteps)`

Get {R, G, B} startColor and endColor
Get R_diff, G_diff, and B_diff

for i in 0 to numSteps {
   arrayReference.append(
          i => {min(startR, endR) + (R_diff * (i / numSteps)),
                min(startG, endG) + (G_diff * (i / numSteps)),
                min(startB, endB) + (B_diff * (i / numSteps))}
          )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [hexdec](http://php.net/hexdec), [dechex](http://php.net/dechex) and this snippet:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 255; $i++) {
    # here happens some colour-magic
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: if `// here happens some *** magic` was the answer to everything, the world would be a better place -.-

Comment: Yep, because that would mean, that people wanting to accomplish some task would google "hex color code" and try and learn themselves instead of just asking as the first option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you need all of those colors you could build the 16776960 element array as follows:

```
<?php
    $end = 'FFFFFF';

    $arrMassiveColor = array();

    for($curr = 0; $curr <= dechex($end); $curr++) {
        $arrMassiveColor[] = '#'.hexdec($curr);
    }
?>
```

It seems a bit odd though...

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question - and surprisingly I could not find an actual solution for this on the web (I did not try hard). Performance is besides the point here - this is not what you would want to do - this is just an exercise - but if you actually wanted to iterate over all hex colors - here is how you could do it:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 16777215; $i++) {
    echo sprintf('%06s', dechex($i));
}
```

Of course this question is old and answered, but thought I would share this anyway.