# Reverse a functions output

Tags: php

I have some code that I got from here: [Color coding based on number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533297/color-coding-based-on-number)

```
function GreenYellowRed($number) {
  $number--; // working with 0-99 will be easier

  if ($number < 50) {
    // green to yellow
    $r = floor(255 * ($number / 50));
    $g = 255;

  } else {
    // yellow to red
    $r = 255;
    $g = floor(255 * ((50-$number%50) / 50));
  }
  $b = 0;

  return "$r,$g,$b";
}
```

I am then calling it on a percentage output... like this:

```
"<span style='background-color: rgb(" . GreenYellowRed($percentage) . ")'>" . $percentage . "%</span>"
```

It works as expected, but it makes lower numbers green and higher numbers red. In my case, low percentage is bad and high percentage is good, but I can't work out what to change to make it work in reverse so that hight numbers go green and low numbers go red.

I've tried a few things but it never seems to do what I want... can anyone help?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chnge this:

```
return "$r,$g,$b";
```

to this:

```
return "$g,$r,$b";
```

Answer (score -2):

Soooo easy when I thought about it!!

All I had to do was to swap $r and $g on each side of the if statement, like this:

```
function GreenYellowRed($number)
            {
                $number--; // working with 0-99 will be easier

                if ($number < 50) {
                // green to yellow
                $g = floor(255 * ($number / 50));
                $r = 255;

                } else {
                // yellow to red
                $g = 255;
                $r = floor(255 * ((50-$number%50) / 50));
                }
                $b = 0;

                return "$r,$g,$b";
            }
```

All sorted :)