# Dynamic table row background color based on number/percent - color scale

Tags: jquery, css

I have table of data that has a column called percent. I would like the background color of the cells in that column to depend on the value in that cell. So if <= -8, the color would be red. If -4 the color would be yellow. If >=0 then green. But should be a gradient so that the numbers in between like 2.2 would be between yellow and green. Can anyone help me with an example that I could use for my specific task? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is inspired from the accepted answer to this question,

[Color coding based on number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533297/color-coding-based-on-number)

```
function GreenYellowRed(value) {
  value--;
  
  var r,g,b;

  if (value < 4) {
    // green to yellow
    r = Math.floor(255 * (value / 4));
    g = 255;

  } else {
    // yellow to red
    r = 255;
    g = Math.floor(255 * ((4-value%4) / 4));
  }
 b = 0;

  return r + "," + g + "," + b;
}
```

Working JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vu1b1m57/

**Update**
Please see the new JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vu1b1m57/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. That is awesome. Can I bother you with a follow-up question, since I am not very learned in JavaScript? Using your example, how would I apply the background color to the cells within the one column of  my table that have the different values?

Comment: Please check the update. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Fantastic. Exactly what I was looking for. I can't thank you enough. I am trying to play with the color values though and am getting close to what I need but not quite there. The scale currently goes from green to red as the numbers get higher. I am looking for it to go from red to green with red starting at -8. Yellow starting at -4 and green starting at 1. Is that doable with this example? Since I am not familiar with the math.floor logic, I am not quite sure how to do it correctly. Thank you again!

Comment: I am not as good with this relations between the numbers and colors but I have updated the fiddle after some trail and errors. https://jsfiddle.net/vu1b1m57/3/. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I honestly do not know what to say. I wish there was a way I could repay you for this. Thank you so much!